# standing waves on a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, string

I've a problem that I can't solve, could someone please help me?

The problem says:

> Two strings of a bass vibrate in a normal oscillation mode with the same period of 8.0 milliseconds. If the tension in one of the strings is decreased by 7 N a beat frequency of 6 Hz is heard.
>
> Determine:
>   - The period of oscillation of the string with the reduced tension.
>   - The initial tension in both strings.

My attempt to solve this exercise:

I used the period to calculate the frequency:
$T_1 = 8ms = 0.008s$ 
so the frequency is $$f_1 = 1/T = 125Hz$$

The beat frequency heard is $6Hz$ so the new frequency (the one in the string with the lower tension) is $$f_2 = 125-6 = 119Hz$$.  Therefore the new period is $T_2=  1/119Hz = 8.4 ms$.

Now I've tried to solve the second part but i couldn't.

My difficulty is that I can't calculate the tension because in order to do that I should have more information about the string which I don't.

Is my reasoning right?

Thanks!

Edit: The formula that relates frequency to tension, mass and length for each string is
$$f_1 =\frac{n}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T_1}{\frac{m}{L}}}$$
and 
$$f_2 =\frac{n}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T_2}{\frac{m}{L}}}$$ where $T_2 = T_1 - 7$

$$\frac{f_1}{f_2} = \sqrt{\frac{T_1}{T_2}}$$
$$\frac{f_1^2}{f_2^2} = \frac{T_1}{T_2} $$
$$(f_1^2 - f_2^2)*T_1 = f_1^2 * (7) $$
And finally 
$$ T_1 = \frac{7f_1^2}{f_1^2 - f_2^2} \approx 74.7 N $$

Is this right?

Comment: You mean "tension" not "voltage" - I am afraid your translation software let you down. Do you know the relationship between mass per unit length, tension, length, and frequency of the fundamental mode of a string? That's where you have to start. And note - we don't "do your homework for you" - you have to do most of the work, we will help with concepts. But you have to clarify what concept you are struggling with.

Comment: Hi , i've edited the question with all my reasoning, I speak another language so it is hard for me trying to explain this kind of concepts.

Comment: As Floris says, try writing down the formula which relates period to tension, mass and length for each string.  Then decide if you have enough information to find the initial tension.

Comment: I've edited the post , is that formula correct? Thanks

Comment: You are getting close. You have the ratio of tensions from the ratio of frequencies squared; and you have their difference. Two equations, two unknowns. Solve.

Comment: I know the frequencies too, $f_1 = 125Hz, f_2 = 119Hz $ am I right? I've edited it in a more clearly way. Thanks.

Comment: There appears to be an algebra error in your work, in the next-to-last equation.

Comment: Yes, I've written 74.3N instead of 74.7N. But the thing that matters for me is the reasonig? So it is right, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you solved your problem by yourself. Well done.